# Check If an Object Already Exists at a Location

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting to do a check to see if there is an object at a particular location on the screen. I have an image view with frame (7, 545, 75, 75) and another image view that moves.  I do not want it to be able to move to the same location as the other image view so I need to be able to tell if an object exists in the location I'm trying to move to.

Here is my code for the moving image view:

```
- (IBAction)moveForward:(id)sender
{
    moveForwardCards--;
    forwardLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i left", moveForwardCards];

    if (moveForwardCards == 0)
    {
        forwardButton.enabled = NO;
    }

    if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x, turtle.frame.origin.y + 90, 75, 75);
    }
    else if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x, turtle.frame.origin.y - 90, 75, 75);
    }
    else if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x + 90, turtle.frame.origin.y, 75, 75);
    }
    else if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x - 90, turtle.frame.origin.y, 75, 75);
    }

    NSLog(@"turtle frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(turtle.frame));
}
```

Comment: Look for `CGRectIntersectsRect()`.

Comment: Well, "an object" exists there, since there is always the underlying view.  You can check whether two objects intersect if you have pointers to the two objects.  Otherwise, you can start at the root of the view and search the child views recursively for an intersection.  (Tedious, but I've had to do it on a couple of occasions.)